# Unusual form HTML, or browser issue?

Tags: html, css, forms, firefox

I am experiencing an issue with Firefox (tested with FF5/win, FF6/win, FF5/mac) having wider margins than any other browser I've tested. (IE9/win, Chrome/win, Opera/win, Safari/win, Safari/mac).

Admittedly, the HTML is unusual, I have 5 forms in a row, but I cannot find any documented problems with the idea, or any warning against it.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); float: left; height: 82px; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 12px; width: 502px;">
    <span style="color: #514536; font-weight: bold;">Search By Destination:</span><br />
    <div id="regions" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        <form action="/view-the-collection/" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="dest" name="dest" value="Caribbean" />
            <input type="hidden" id="search" name="search" value="1" />
            <button class="imgbtn" type="submit">
                <img src="/a/i/pe_carrib_region.jpg" alt="Caribbean" />
            </button>
        </form>
        <form action="/view-the-collection/" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="dest" name="dest" value="Mexico" />
            <input type="hidden" id="search" name="search" value="1" />
            <button class="imgbtn" type="submit">
                <img src="/a/i/pe_mexico_region.jpg" alt="Mexico" />
            </button>
        </form>
        <form action="/view-the-collection/" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="dest" name="dest" value="Thailand" />
            <input type="hidden" id="search" name="search" value="1" />
            <button class="imgbtn" type="submit">
                <img src="/a/i/pe_thailand_region.jpg" alt="Thailand" />
            </button>
        </form>
        <form action="/view-the-collection/" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="dest" name="dest" value="Southern US" />
            <input type="hidden" id="search" name="search" value="1" />
            <button class="imgbtn" type="submit">
                <img src="/a/i/pe_southus_region.jpg" alt="Southern US" />
            </button>
        </form>                     
        <form action="/view-the-collection/" method="post" style="margin-right: 0px;">
            <input type="hidden" id="dest" name="dest" value="Mustique" />
            <input type="hidden" id="search" name="search" value="1" />
            <button class="imgbtn" type="submit">
                <img src="/a/i/pe_mustique_region.jpg" alt="Mustique" />
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div><br style="clear: both;" />
```

CSS

```
#container #regions form {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 14px 13px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

For most browsers, it renders like this:

[image]

Except in Firefox, which looks like:

[image]

I've made sure to remove padding and margins from every element in each of these forms, and it has no effect. I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this, whether it is a browser incompatibility, or whether what I've coded is completely out of line. Can anyone advise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if instead of using margin, you just add padding to the right?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I think I have an idea what the problem is, but I need to test it to confirm my hunch. What version of Firefox?

Comment: @Jonah Katz - I will try that out now.

Comment: @thirtydot - I have reproduced the issue in FF5/win, FF6/win, and FF5/safari. You can view the page at http://www.preferredescapes.com/index2.php

Comment: Yeah, having multiple duplicated `id` attributes is definitely going to drag you down. That needs to be fixed ASAP.

Comment: Agreed. Noticed and corrected shortly after posting. No effect.

Comment: @DaveL: I'm taking a look: it seems weird. Unless someone beats me to it, you can count on me either answering this or leaving a comment telling you I can't work it out :)

Comment: @Jonah Katz - I've replaced the right margins with right paddings, and it renders the same way. Wider in Firefox than any other browser. So strange. DOM inspectors in Firefox and other browsers show the same property values, and Firefox does respond to having the values changed, just not the same as other browsers. :(

Comment: @thirtydot - Appreciate the help, friend.

Comment: @DaveL Check out my new answer below. I just tested in in Firefox and it works! (PS. Google Firebug if you want to debug quicker/easier in the future)

Comment: @Jonah Katz - Thanks again, friend. I actually do have firebug (on top of using Webkits document inspector), but had a braindead moment, and didn't look at the widths. I won't make that mistake again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres a fix. Instead of adding margins to the forms, just set their widths to `97px` each, and align the buttons/images to the left!!

Comment: THIS IS A WINNER! Thank you so much! I hadn't considered the default widths of the elements.

Thanks for the kind words, too. Our design team is pretty brilliant. I'm very happy to work with them.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a browser compatibility issue. I would suggest you using a CSS-reset like the HTML5 Boilerplate: http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but the site is far enough along in it's development, and time/budget is so narrow, I would like to leave this as a last resort.

Comment: Gave an upvote because a CSS reset likely would have solved this issue.

Comment: @DaveL Thanks. Have you tried to check your website with older/newer Firefox versions?

Answer (score 2):

The extra space looks just about wide enough to be inter-word spaces. Does it go away if you try and cull away all whitespace between your HTML tags (ie between the `<form>`s and between the various parts of each form)?

Comment: Interesting thought! I have seen whitespace cause problems, particularly with the <textarea> tag, so I revised the HTML shown here so that it was all on one line with no space between tags, and unfortunately, it hasn't helped. Upvote given, though, as I wouldn't have thought of that myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very good and well referenced css package called [**Formalize CSS** - Teach your forms some manners!](http://formalize.me/)  to make the look and feel of your html form elements cross browser and cross os compatibility.